# how to install cmake file offline without updates on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

My OS is ubuntu and i try to install the cmake file above version 3.1. I have cmake version 2.8.12 in my system. It is possible to update or install cmake 3.1 without get ubuntu system updated(sudo apt-get update or upgrade)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can download the installer [here](https://cmake.org/download/). Scroll down to *`Binary distributions`* and there *`Linux x86_64`*. There are two versions:

- `*.sh`: Install script; execute and you are done
- `*.tar.gz`*: Contains all the binaries etc.; extract and if necessary add the path to `PATH` variable

---

## TL;DR

```
curl -sSL https://cmake.org/files/v3.9/cmake-3.9.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -o install.sh
chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh --prefix=/usr/local --skip-license
```

***Tips:*** You can change the install path with the `--prefix` option. You can pick any CMake version by changing the download link.

Answer (score 0):

You're on Ubuntu 14.04?  You really should upgrade to a newer LTS like 16.04...

Having said that, I guess you're trying to install a program that has a minimum cmake requirement of 3.1?  You could try to install CMake from source by downloading it from [here](https://cmake.org/download/).  I personally think that's your best option.

There are ways with apt-get to update just cmake but I worry there there are too many dependencies.  For example, if you look at the [list of dependencies](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/cmake) for CMake in Ubuntu 14.04, there is libc6, gcc, etc.  These are important packages for any system so I *guess* that it will be hard to update just CMake using Ubuntu's packaging system while keeping them at their current versions.

You can try downloading a later version of CMake by looking [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cmake) but this is a very bad idea.  And I think it will fail since when you install it with "dpkg -i", it will continually complaining about a dependency that you're not installing.  But I'm just letting you know as another option.